# Expected Value - Uniform distribution over infinite interval

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Question:

The probability that an error is introduced into a packet is $\alpha$. Messages, consisting of one or more packets, are received at a node. Given that a message has been received free of errors, what is the expected number of packets in it? Assume that packets are never lost and that messages of all lengths are equally likely.

I know I need to find the expected value and use the uniform distribution, but since it could range from length = 1 to infinity I'm unsure.  What I'm starting with:
$$E[X]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha^kf_X(k)$$

Since its a uniform distribution I thought $f_X(k)$ would be a constant so I have:
$$E[X]=f_X(k)\big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha^k\big)$$
$$E[X]=f_X(k)*\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}$$

Any hints on what to do next (how to compute the pdf when infinity is involved) or corrections would be appreciated.

Comment: It is mathematically not possible for all message lengths to be equally likely.

Comment: This is just the question I was given - if that's correct and that assumption is wrong, what would be the more likely scenario?

Comment: One would have to specify a genuine probability distribution. I do not know what type of distribution is commonly used in making models for message length.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused why a uniform distribution for message length would not work.  Does it have something to do with uniform distributions and infinity?

Comment: Let the probability that a message has length $n$ be $p\gt 0$. Then the probability it has length $1$, plus the probbility it has length $2$, plus $\dots$ is infinite. But always the sum of the probabilities over the (discrete) sample space is $1$.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll ask for clarification on the problem then.

Comment: You are welcome. Basically for the same reason, one cannot habe a uniform distribution on an infinite interval.